# Showing whats happening within a $_POST within a callback function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, callback

I am having an issue with my code and I was wanting to know is there away that I can show my `$_POST` that is in my controller to see what is happening:

In my `jQuery` code my `ajaxCall` function is built in the following format `n ajaxCall(url, data_array, div_id, callback_fn)`

I have done `console.log(data_array);` and its showing the correct data but is there away to see whats happening within the `callback_fn` as its not saving to the DB?

**Since all of my codes have returned 200 with no errors I have gone back to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973390/mysql-insert-into-db-not-working)**

**Ajax Code:**

```
$('body').on("click", "#product_save_youtube_btn", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var box = $("#product_youtube");
        var id = box.data("id"); 

        var url = box.data("url");              
        var data_array = { 
                id : id, 
                new_id : box.val(), 
            };

            //console.log(data_array);

        if($.trim(box.val()) != "")
        {
            ajaxCall(url, data_array, null, "update_product_youtube");

            alert("Your You Tube ID Has Been Changed");
        }           

    });
```

**ajaxCall:**

```
function ajaxCall(url, data_array, div_id, callback_fn) {

        return $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:url,
            beforeSend: function(){
                 $("#" + div_id).html("<img src='http://www.domain.co.nz/files/large/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Loading..' title='Loading..'/>");
            },
            data:data_array,
            complete:function (data) {
               $("#" + div_id).html(data.responseText);

               if(callback_fn != null)
               {
                   eval(callback_fn + '()');
               }
            }
        });
    }
```

**PHP Code - Callback_fn:**

```
public function ajax_update_product_youtube()
        {
            if($_POST)
            {
                $id = intval($_POST['id']);
                $new_id = mysqli_real_escpe_string(trim($_POST['new_id']));

                if(empty($id))
                {
                    $this->Ps_products_model->update_product_youtube($id, $new_id);
                }                           
            }
        }
```

**Model:**

```
public function update_product_youtube($table, $id, $new_id)
    {
        $table = $this->_table_products;

       $this->db->query("UPDATE {$table} SET youtube = ? WHERE id = ?", array($new_id, $id));
    }
```

Comment: Why not just look in your server log? If you are running apache locally any errors thrown should show up there.

Comment: I am not getting anything related to the controller and model and all the names are correct etc

Comment: What does the browser network tab show you when making the ajax request?

Comment: @DanielNill Its showing all OK

Comment: Please show us the code of your `ajaxCall()` function. That's what you need to modify in order to see what's coming back.

Comment: I would suggest using Netbeans and Xdebug for your debugging purposes.

Comment: @JessMcKenzie if it is showing the request is returning a 200 then it is likely an issue with how you are saving to the db. Can you give us some more information showing the code you are using to save to the db and what mvc framework you're using?

Comment: @DanielNill I am using CI - and the rest is above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're asking how to debug an ajax request.  There are a number of things you can do here.  First if you are sure the error is occurring on the server side, in chrome or firefox you can check the network tab in the developer console.  This will list all requests that your page makes as well and request and response parameters being passed.  If the controller method is throwing a php or sql error is will be returned as the response unless you've set php to silence all thrown errors.

To do this make sure your php settings have

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to see the response of your controller.
To do this, you can do one of the following :

1. Use [hurl.it](http://www.hurl.it/) and manually send your params to see response.
2. Use chrome dev tools / firebug. if in chrome, you can press F12 -> console -> right click on console -> choose log xmlHttpRequests. All your ajax requests and responses will be logged and viewable.

Comment: Thanks,  Still no errors etc unsure why its not saving into the DB

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a quick and dirty debug hack, just `var_dump` whatever variables (for example, `$_POST`) you want to see from within your controller/callback function.

Comment: It does show up in the response, you just need to use proper debug tools (such as chrome dev tools or firebug) to make it visible.